# Deleting with Joins

Tags: mysql, sql

I can't figure out how to delete the words that belong to a specific file. I'm trying to delete words that have belong to the file with fileId 42. Anyone think they can help me?

```
Table file
fileId - Primary Key
fileName - Normal column.
fileUrl - Normal column.

Table fileWord
fileId, wordId - Primary Key, Foreign Key
count - Normal column.

Table word
wordId - Primary Key
word - Normal Column
```

My SQL:

```
DELETE words
FROM files f, fileword fw, words w
WHERE 42 = fw.fileId AND fw.wordId = w.wordId;
```

Comment: could you format the tables correctly with PK,FK ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
DELETE f FROM files as f
inner join fileword as fw on f.fileId = fw.wordId 
inner join words as w on f.fileId = w.wordId
WHERE f.fileId = 42
```

if you want to delete a word from words table then

```
DELETE w FROM files as f
inner join fileword as fw on f.fileId = fw.wordId 
inner join words as w on fw.wordId = w.wordId
WHERE f.fileId = 42
```

Comment: I tried this code, and it didn't seem to work. I'm trying to delete all the words. (Your second example)

Comment: @user1932934 BGS is right as per information .. and what do do you mean with `it didn't seem to work.` ..  waht actually happens please explain  means if records it may be issue is you are using INNER JOIN and you might not have appropriate records exists in db ..

Comment: I'm trying to delete all words from the words table that belong to a specific file.

I meant it didn't work as in it was successful but nothing was deleted.

Comment: Is the table contains the fileID? Whether wordID column refers to the fileID? There one column sholud be there for mapping this word mapped with this particular file. use that column in where condition.

Comment: If your table values contain the field id 42 then , above script should be delete all records(words) belongs to filed id 42.

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to delete that particular file from "files" table alone. If yes please try the below code,

```
DELETE
FROM files f, fileword fw, words w
WHERE f.fileId = 42
and f.fileId = fw.wordId 
and f.fileId = w.wordId;
```

Comment: I'm trying to delete words. I forgot to specify.